# fixpoint feature in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, system-generator

when I am using simulink, the following warning appear to me

```
Warning: Support for ver('fixpoint') will be removed in a future release.
```

and the fixpoint feature is very important to my work (working with system generator)

Please, can anyone help me how to install or add this feature to my MATLAB (R2013a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a name change that The Mathworks is implementing.

In R2016a, the warning is a bit more clear:
Warning: Support for ver('fixpoint') will be removed in a future release.  Use ver('fixedpoint') instead.